# What is the WMI class for ASP .NET Apps v2.0*?

Tags: .net, windows, wmi

When I pull the win32* classes locally I am not seeing a class that refers to the ASP.NET Apps v.2.0.50727 counters which show up in the perfmon gui. How do I pull WMI info for 2.0 applications on Windows 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running PowerShell to match any WMI classes in `root\cimv2`:

```
gwmi -List "*asp*" | ft Name
```

gives:

```
Name
----
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETAppsv2050727
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETAppsv2050727
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETv2050727
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET2050727_ASPNETv2050727
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETAppsv4030319
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET4030319_ASPNETv4030319
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNET
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNET
Win32_PerfFormattedData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
Win32_PerfRawData_ASPNET_ASPNETApplications
Win32_PerfFormattedData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService
Win32_PerfRawData_aspnetstate_ASPNETStateService
Win32_PerfFormattedData_RemoteAccess_RASPort
Win32_PerfRawData_RemoteAccess_RASPort
```

(I don't think "`.`" is valid in a WMI class name, hence the naming.)

Also, with `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter` you can read a performance counter directly, you don't need to go via WMI.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I pulled the class thru VB and figured out that WMI was pulling an error on this server when attempting to retrieve 2.0 counters. There's a hotfix for this...

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951683